# System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has timed out. error in asp.net send mail code using godaddy hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, sendmail, smtpclient

I am using following peace of code to send mail using godaddy hosting .

but its throw **`System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has timed out.`**

```
protected void sendmail()
    {
        var fromAddress = "frommailid@site.com";
        // any address where the email will be sending
        var toAddress = "to@gmail.com";
        //Password of your gmail address
        const string fromPassword = "mypassword";
        // Passing the values and make a email formate to display
        string subject = "HI test mail ";
        string body = "From: pro@e-hotelspro.com";
        // smtp settings
        var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
        {
            //smtp.Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
            smtp.Host = "smtpout.secureserver.net";
            smtp.Port = 80;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
            smtp.Timeout = 20000;
        }
        // Passing values to smtp object
        smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);
    }
```

Comment: I believe smtp port with ssl should be 465

Comment: let me check this also ..thanks for your time.

Comment: Why not check with the people who run your SMTP server which port you're meant to be using? There's nothing wrong with the code, so asking here is pointless - all we can do is guess your network config.

Comment: @rahularyansharma did you solve your issue man, iam also  facing the same error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is the famous SSL issue of System.Net.Mail

[System.Net.Mail with SSL to authenticate against port 465](https://web.archive.org/web/20100215001207/http://blogs.msdn.com/webdav_101/archive/2008/06/02/system-net-mail-with-ssl-to-authenticate-against-port-465.aspx)

You should use some external library or wait until Microsoft include this features in a framework release

Comment: That link is dead.

Comment: @Dunc not anymore! god saves the internet archive

Answer (score -4):

Just Change:

`smtp.Timeout = 20000;`

To

`smtp.Timeout = 2000000;`

Comment: LOL. How about "client.Timeout = int.MaxValue;"?

Comment: Why you put int.MaxValue?
Why this answer is LOL?