# C# SMTP send email error

Tags: c#, email, controller, smtp

I'm attempting to add in the ability to send a contact request on a website.
I have all the client side code set up, however I have an error on the server side code.

[image]

I can't seem to see whats wrong with my code. I've never attempted to do such a task before, so I would appreciate it if anyone could let me know where I am going wrong.

I am trying to send the an email to myself (same outgoing and incoming email address) with a standard header, but different body which is passed as parameters.

Edit: realised that I had posted a photo of the code rather than pasting the actual code so here it is:

```
public void btn_send_Click(string name, string phoneNumber, string text, string email)
{
    var fromAddress = new MailAddress("-----.co.uk", "From Name");
    var toAddress = new MailAddress("------.co.uk", "To Name");

    const string fromPassword = "-----";
    const string subject = "NEW CONTACT REQUEST";

    string body = text + "\n" + name + "\n" + phoneNumber + "\n" + email;

    var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "mail3.gridhost.co.uk",
                Port = 465,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
            };

    using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body
    })
    {
        smtp.Send(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: This has already been answered.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828304/system-net-mail-smtpexception-the-operation-has-timed-out-error-in-asp-net-sen

Comment: @Maertin Ah thank you for the link - changing the port to another my host allows has solved it.